# MySQL command line client crashes

Tags: mysql

While I try to source a .sql file of size 6GB, MySQL command line client crashes abruptly without even throwing any error.

I tried to set `max_allowed_packet` to a limit of `16M` and tried `SET @@local.net_read_timeout=360;`.

The SQL file does not have any command that is likely to close the connection. Only table creation and value insertion commands are there. Since the crash is abrupt, can't figure out the root cause.

Can anyone help me in analyzing this further?

Comment: Have you tried using [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)?

Comment: Is MySQL server located in any resource that you have access to?... I think the troubleshooting should be done from server side looking at mysql-error.log... From client side is quite hard to get something clear.

Comment: Pre-process your file to be <= 1GB will be a requirement. 
Share your my.cnf/ini with us and we will be able to provide tips on smoothing your experience with a 6GB source input file.  General Log for your effort would be helpful as well as the error,log.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! The problem was with the unzipping process which retained unnecessary encoding characters at the end of the 6GB file. Even after unzipping the file from zip format, encoded characters were not removed. Figured it out and removed the unnecessary characters.

Comment: @tadman Tried using workbench and it helped to narrow down the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a Linux box, try running the command with strace

`strace -ff -o mysql.strace <your mysql cmd>`

Log at mysql.strace.[PID] can show how far the execution went.